# Updating LinqDataSource from separate DataContext

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I want to update one LinqDataSource with a record retrieved from a different DataContext. The problem is that the DataContext of the LinqDataSource doesn't seem to be made public so I can't get access to it to attach the new object to the DataSource's context.

What is the normal way of doing this? Or should I just scrap the LinqDataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good reason for that - you can't share objects across different DataContexts.

If you use the LinqDataSource's OnContextCreating event you can attach the correct instance to the data source [ie, that which the second entity is retrieved from] so they're both from the same DataContext:

ASPX:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource .... OnContextCreating="GetDataContext" ... />
```

C#:

```
protected void GetDataContext(object sender, LinqDataSourceContextEventArgs e)
{
    e.ObjectInstance = MyDataContext.Current; // assuming that Current is the ambient instance
}
```